# React Router Matching any Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to match a route in my application using react-router, but I'm not having success...

There are big paths like:

> localhost:8080/some-path-1/some-subpath-3/another-sub-path-4
>
> localhost:8080/some-path-2/some-subpath-3/another-sub-path-6
>
> localhost:8080/some-path-5/some-subpath-4/another-sub-path-1

My main component is rendering like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <Router history={ history }>
            <Route path="*" component={ ReactProject } />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I've seen in react-router docs that '*' path matches all characters untill the next /, ? or #, but, is there a way to make it match all characters independent of the length of the path?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to render the same ReactProject component for every route?

Comment: Yes, all I want is render ReactProject component independent of the length of the path... My component renders until the next "/", so, when I have localhost:8080/some-path, it works, but if I have localhost:8080/some-path/some-subpath, it won't work

Comment: If the objective is just rendering same component for any path, then why not use
<DefaultRoute component={ReactProject} />

Comment: I can render the same component with the code above, but when I try to refresh the page I get an error 404, (js file not found)... DefaultRoute doesnt works for me :\